# Linq null reference value match from database id

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

in my code there is a ddlitemid that can be null and in Linq query my code is like

```
valuecheck = _allQuestions.Where(x => x.nID == ddlItemId).FirstOrDefault().strName;
```

if ddlitemid not exist in my database it gives error i wants to handle null reference object error

Comment: You should probably look at this question/answer here first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948369/how-to-handle-null-values-in-linq - I think that's what you are looking for?

Comment: hi i saw that earlier my pattern is different than that question so that's why i ask question ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this pattern `FirstOrDefault().SomeProperty` very often. It has two drawbbacks.

1. You always need to do a null check on `FirstOrDefault()`.
2. It is not efficient.

About the second point: `FirstOrDefault()` grabs a whole entity from the database and you use only one field from it. You can kill two birds with one stone by doing:

```
valuecheck = _allQuestions.Where(x => x.nID == ddlItemId)
                          .Select(q => q.strName)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or `.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty`.

Answer (score 2):

Then separate the call to `FirstOrDefault` from the access of `strName`.  Also you can remove the `Where` and put the lambda filter into the `FirstOrDefault`.

```
var quesiton = _allQuestions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nID == ddlItemId);
if(question != null)
{
    valuecheck = question.strName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I normally handle this is to assign my linq results to a variable and then check for null.

```
var tempStorage = _allQuestions.Where(x => x.nID == ddlItemId).FirstOrDefault();

if(tempStorage != null)
{
    valuecheck = tempStorage.strName;
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about the null ref exception since you check the existence first.